# Parse Push PHP SDK not able to receive on Android device

Tags: php, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to send a parse push message using PHP code and Parse PHP SDK to all the Android Devices which are already registered.
The Parse SDK is available here [Parse PHP SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk) and I used the **Alternative Method** provided in the link above.

My PHP File:

```
<?php
      $APPLICATION_ID = "...";
      $REST_API_KEY = "...";
      $MASTER_KEY = "...";
      require 'autoload.php';
      use Parse\ParsePush;
      use Parse\ParseClient;
      ParseClient::initialize($APPLICATION_ID, $REST_API_KEY, $MASTER_KEY);

      $data = array("alert" => "Test Message");

      // Push
      ParsePush::send(array(
                      "data" => $data
      ));
?>
```

My environment is **WAMP** running latest version and followed the instructions given in above website. 
But when I open the PHP file in Browser. I get *errors* like undefined `_curl_init()_` **shown in screenshot**. I did my best searching on Google and stuff but I personally feel the documentation of Parse.com is not good.

I need bit help with this issue.

[image: Error Screenshot]

---

**EDIT** : I solved this issue by adding 
`curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` below `$rest = curl_init();` in `ParseClient.php`

Yet I'm unable to receive notification on my device

Answer (score 0):

you also use ParseInstallation class

```
<?php

      $APPLICATION_ID = "...";
      $REST_API_KEY = "...";
      $MASTER_KEY = "...";
      require 'autoload.php';

    use Parse\ParseClient;
    use Parse\ParseUser;
    use Parse\ParseInstallation;
    use Parse\ParsePush;

 ParseClient::initialize($APPLICATION_ID, $REST_API_KEY, $MASTER_KEY);

    // Send Notification For Specific User
    $data = array (
            "alert" => "Test Message" 
    );

    ParsePush::send ( array (
            "channels" => ["addChannel"],//add data channel from parse.com Installation class enter code here
            "data" => $data 
    ) );
?>
```